# Xcode 8.1 beta (8T29o) SIL error after conversion to Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3

My application was compiling fine before converting to Swift 3.0 & Xcode 8.

Now when I build I get the following,

```
1.  While emitting SIL for 'unwindToLobbyPools' at /.../LobbyPools.swift:254:15
```

I can print the rest of the error if it helps.